# MySQL error when migrating database schema, Doctrine with Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm doing a web application using Symfony Framework with MySQL as the database. I'm using doctrine to do the ORM to map the database. I created the schema and did the doctrine:migrations:diff to verify the queries and check that my relations where in order and they appear to be. But when I want to migrate the new schema to MySQL the following error appears: [Picture of the Command Line describing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4StC.png)

Here's the Business Class

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string")
*/
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
 private $stage_Of_Development;


//Relations

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_email", referencedColumnName="clientEmail")
 */
private $client;


//Getters and Setters

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getClient()
{
    return $this->client;
}

 /**
 * @param mixed $client
 */
public function setClient(Client $client)
{
    $this->client = $client;
}
}
```

Here's the Client Class:

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 */
class Client
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 */
private $clientEmail;    

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getClientEmail()
{
    return $this->clientEmail;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $clientEmail
 */
public function setClientEmail($clientEmail)
{
    $this->clientEmail = $clientEmail;
}   
}
```

Here's the Migration:

namespace Application\Migrations;

```
class Version20170325232622 extends AbstractMigration
{
 /**
  * @param Schema $schema
  */
 public function up(Schema $schema)
 {
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE business ADD client_email VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE business ADD CONSTRAINT FK_8D36E3844FFE0C3 FOREIGN KEY (client_email) REFERENCES client (clientEmail)');
    $this->addSql('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D36E38A89DB457 ON business (business_id)');
    $this->addSql('CREATE INDEX IDX_8D36E3844FFE0C3 ON business (client_email)');
}

/**
 * @param Schema $schema
 */
public function down(Schema $schema)
{
    // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE business DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_8D36E3844FFE0C3');
    $this->addSql('DROP INDEX UNIQ_8D36E38A89DB457 ON business');
    $this->addSql('DROP INDEX IDX_8D36E3844FFE0C3 ON business');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE business DROP client_email');
}
}
```

The schema contains more classes and the client and business entities contain more attributes but for the sake of simplicity I only posted the ones generated the error. I would appreciate anybody's help with this as its my first time using these technologies and I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 3):

During the development phase I often have to "clear" previous migrations and then start fresh. You SHOULD NOT DO THIS if your database is in production!! To start fresh, you can drop the database, re-create it, delete previous migrations, then re-run the diff and migrate. In symfony3, I do this:

```
// WARNING: This will delete your database!!!
>
> bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force
> bin/console doctrine:database:create
> rm -f app/DoctrineMigrations/*
>
> bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
> bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Comment: I tried that but that didn't help. The error still appears. Weirdly enough when I check the database, the foreign keys do appear so I don't understand the error. Any other idea of what could be causing it?

Comment: I had the same issue because I used and generated migrations on a sqlite database in the dev env but my production database was powered by mysql.

Comment: This fixed it for me except my migrations are in src/Migrations

Comment: My answer was written for symfony 3. In symfony 4 and above, you are right, the migrations are in `src/Migrations`.